# cat() doesn't output everytime in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, cat

I have a loop that gets some info from every field from every table, from every database in a list (so 3 nested for loops). because it's difficult to know where I am in the cycle and my internet craps out frequently, I decided to spit out a quick line for each loop cycle... this is what the code looks like:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(conns)){
  ## Connect to each db in the dataframe conns and get a list of the Tables

  ## FOR EACH TABLE
  for (j in 1:length(Tables)){

        ## FOR EACH COLUMN (or field)
        for (k in 1:length(Columns)){
          ## do stuff, and then:

          cat(paste(i," of ",nrow(conns),"; ",round(j/length(Tables)*100,2),"%; ",k,
                      " of ",length(Columns),"; \n",sep=""))

        }


  }
  close(channel)
}
```

And this is what the output of that cat looks like:

```
14 of 14; 43.77%; 1 of 5; 
14 of 14; 43.77%; 2 of 5; 
14 of 14; 43.77%; 3 of 5; 
14 of 14; 43.77%; 4 of 5; 
14 of 14; 43.77%; 5 of 5; 
14 of 14; 44.15%; 1 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.15%; 2 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.15%; 3 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.15%; 4 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.53%; 1 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.53%; 2 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.53%; 3 of 4; 
14 of 14; 44.53%; 4 of 4; 
>
```

and then the loop ends without an error. But why then did it stop at 44.5%? So I decided to check whether the loop had changed manually, and obtained the following output:

```
> length(Tables)
[1] 265
> j
[1] 265
> cat(paste(i," of ",nrow(conns),"; ",round(j/length(Tables)*100,2),"%; ",k,
+ " of ",length(Columns),"; \n",sep=""))
14 of 14; 100%; 4 of 0;
```

So why was the `j` percent stop outputting at 44.53%, while in actuality it was correctly at 100%?

**EDIT**: Full code of for loop structure below:

```
## FOR EACH PROJECT
for (i in 13:nrow(conns)){
  d <- conns[i,1] %>% as.character
  p <- conns[i,3] %>% as.character
  u <- conns[i,2] %>% as.character

  channel <- odbcConnect(d,u,p)

  ## Find out what tables are available
  sqlTables(channel) %>% select(TABLE_NAME) -> Tables 
  Tables <- as.vector(Tables[,1])

  ## Throw out long uuid ones
  Tables <- Tables[!(substr(Tables,9,9) == "-" & nchar(Tables) == 36)]

  ## FOR EACH TABLE
  for (j in 1:length(Tables)){
    ## Check that Table name doesn't have questionmarks or starts with sys
    if (!grepl("\\?|^sys",Tables[j])){
      ##GET COLUMNS
      Columns <- as.data.frame(colnames(
        sqlFetch(channel, Tables[j], rows_at_time = 5,max=1)))
      ## Check that there's at least 1 column
      if (ncol(Columns)!=0){
        Columns <- as.vector(Columns[,1])

        ## FOR EACH COLUMN
        for (k in 1:length(Columns)){
          if(grepl("\\?\\?\\?\\?|DoB",Columns[k])!=T){
            db1[l,1] <- d
            db1[l,2] <- Tables[j]
            db1[l,3] <-  Columns[k]

            AC <- paste('"',as.character(Columns[k]),'"',sep="")
            Q <- paste('SELECT COUNT(',AC,') AS Count1, 
                       COUNT(DISTINCT (',AC,')) AS Count2 FROM "',Tables[j],'"',sep="")
            Result <- sqlQuery(channel, Q, rows_at_time = 5)
            db1[l,4] <- Result[1,1]
            db1[l,5] <- Result[1,2]
            cat(paste(i," of ",nrow(conns),"; ",round(j/length(Tables)*100,2),"%; ",k,
                      " of ",length(Columns),"; \n",sep=""))
            l <- l + 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  close(channel)
}
```

Comment: not enough information to tell, we need a reproducible example ...  Maybe you accidentally created a redundant `j` variable within the body of the `j` loop?

Comment: Adding additional information.

Comment: @AmitKohli It's one of the three `if` statements that is stopping it. For the cases after 44.53%, either `!grepl("\\?|^sys",Tables[j])`, `ncol(Columns)!=0` or `grepl("\\?\\?\\?\\?|DoB",Columns[k])!=T` isn't true.

Comment: @DavidRobinson that's it... `ncol(Columns)!=0` was triggering due to all the extra random tables SQL Azure creates. Good call both of you. Formal answer for rep?

Comment: @AmitKohli, sure, added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of the three if statements that is stopping it from reaching the print statement in the subsequent loops.

For the cases after 44.53%, either `!grepl("\\?|^sys",Tables[j])`, `ncol(Columns)!=0` or `grepl("\\?\\?\\?\\?|DoB",Columns[k])!=T` isn't true.